# How to add a class to a number_field bound to model object

Tags: ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, form-for

No idea why this isn't working, have read through a lot of doc examples, most of those focus on `text_field`, maybe `number_field` is weird? I know that number_field doesn't accept a `length` option...

```
<%= form_for @person do |p| %>
  <%= p.number_field :zipcode, class: "short-number-field" %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

The html never renders with the class, how do I do this?

Note, this is not a `number_field_tag`, so the number of arguments is 2.

Thanks!

Comment: your code works just fine for me, maybe you see cached version?

Comment: I cleared cache... nothing! The only way I got this to work was by targeting the ID. Whatever, I'm over this random error...